# How to use class SalesOrganizationLink

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I need to retrieve from S4HC the following information: which plants are assigned to a sales organization (in ECC table TVKWZ). Snooping around, I found out the class [SalesOrganizationLink](https://help.sap.com/doc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/index.html) which I believe gives me such info. However, I could not instantiate it.

Usually, I get a service class that allows me to retrieve data (i.e., sales order service). I could not find the service class for this case.

Could someone give a hint on how to use this class?

BR,
Pietro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SalesOrganizationLink` class is used by the VDM to represent navigational properties of a `SalesOrganization`. They hold no information on their own.

If what you are looking for is a navigational property on `SalesOrganization` you can use the `DefaultSalesOrganizationService` and expand the naivgational property:

```
service.getSalesOrganizationByKey("MyKey")
    .select(SalesOrganization.TO_MY_NAVIGATION_PROPERTY)
    .execute(myDestination);
```

But I see no property related to "plants" in the SalesOrganization. Please refer to the [API Hub](https://api.sap.com/api/API_SALESORGANIZATION_SRV/resource) for what is available on the services.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the class you're looking for is `DefaultSalesOrganizationService`.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for the info.  By using such a class, it gives me the type "SalesOrganization". I need the type "SalesOrganizationLink".